# Hierarchical Connect By Pass Value to children

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query, connect-by

I have a hierarchical SQL Statement, which show me a hierarchical list of components of a product. For example: Part 1101400004 contains Part 1012444. And Part 1012444 contains B30048. For each component i have a Qty.

Now my question is: is it possible, to pass a value to the children?

So when part 1101400004 has QTY 0, no matter what QTY Part 1012444 has, it should be 0 because the parent part has QTY zero. And this logic to the bottom of the tree.

```
  select part_no, component_part, qty_per_assembly   
  FROM STRUCTURE MS
  CONNECT BY PRIOR MS.COMPONENT_PART = MS.PART_NO
  START WITH MS.PART_NO  = '1101400004'
```

Result

[image]

Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle version 10g you can use `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` pseudocolumn like this:

```
select part_no, component_part, connect_by_root qty_per_assembly   
  FROM STRUCTURE MS
  CONNECT BY PRIOR MS.COMPONENT_PART = MS.PART_NO
  START WITH MS.PART_NO  = '1101400004'
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm#i2069380

Comment: Thx for your answer.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Is it possible to bind that connect_by_root to a condition? My problem is, i only want to pass the value to the childs if the qty is  0. If the qty is not 0, i want to see the specific qty of the child.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to get quantity from **qty_per_assembly** if all prents not equal "0" and "0" if at least one predecessor is equal "0". For solve it you may use combintion of connect_by_root(component_part) and analytic MIN. Please correct me if I wrong

```
 select part_no, component_part, DECODE(MIN(qty_per_assembly) OVER (PARTITION BY connect_by_root(component_part) ORDER BY level) 
                                       , 0
                                       , 0
                                       , qty_per_assembly)
  FROM STRUCTURE MS
  CONNECT BY PRIOR MS.COMPONENT_PART = MS.PART_NO
  START WITH MS.PART_NO  = '1101400004'
```

EDIT: connect_by_root(qty_per_assembly) change to connect_by_root(component_part)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But its not working like it should. Parent "1101400004" has a child "W41620" with QTY 1

Comment: And W41620 has a child B2345 with QTY 1 but the select shows now a 0.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I make a mistake  `connect_by_root(qty_per_assembly)` should be `connect_by_root(component_part)`